# Using multithreading to read safely from an array that is being written to

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to set up a program that uses a thread to write to an array from a BufferedReader, and another to read from it.

However, if the read result is null (i.e. read index is ahead of write index), I want it to wait, then access the same index again.

I've tried using synchronized statements and read() and notify() like this.

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
String[] lines = new String[n];

Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            synchronized(lines) {
                lines[i] = br.readLine();
                    lines.notify();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
});

t1.start();

Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            String get = lines[i];

            if (get == null) {
                synchronized (lines) {
                    lines.wait();
                }
                continue;
            }

            add(representString(lines[i]), hmap);

            i++;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
});

t2.start();
```

Problem is, I have a suite of tests that would sometimes freeze, but sometimes work. (I don't have a background in multithreading, I'm just learning from online tutorials to do a non-concurrency assignment faster.)

Comment: How do you determine the number of lines to be read?

Comment: That's handled by the main thread right before these statements here by reading from input (the first br.readLine()).

Comment: That’s nice - without more context, it could be you’re expecting more lines then are available, but since we can’t run it, the same way you do, it’s impossible to provide you with support

Comment: I've updated my code snippet to include 2 more lines at the top (first 2 lines, essentially) - if that helps.

Comment: You're getting `null`s for one of two reasons.  Either you're not filling the array correctly or you're reading beyond the end of the file

Comment: But if I were to do it all sequentially in the main thread, it works fine every time. The algorithm is identical, except that I've set different threads to run them, so I'm inclined to believe that the issue is with improper multithreading implementation.

Comment: Well, based on my (limited) testing, it mostly works.  I did create the instance of the `BufferedReader` within the context of the first thread, since you've still not provided a runnable example which demonstrates your issue

Comment: *I'm just learning from online tutorials to do a non-concurrency assignment faster.* How many lines are we talking about? Alone the process of creating those two threads and the sync overhead might nullify all performance gains. Dont be disappointed if your final code is **slower** than the super simple "just read all lines into memory in one shot" alternative. Learning multi threading is helpful, but I am pretty sure that your *goal* (increasing performance) is focusing on the wrong thing. The bottleneck will be IO read performance, nothing else.

Comment: Ranging from 50 to 300,000. I'm thinking of enabling multi-threading only for 100,000 and above. Is 100,000s large enough for it to make a difference?